# Razor view HTML output is different on localhost and server

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, user-interface, razor

We have developed UI for our API using razor view.

This is how the page looks on localhost:
[the page on localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdMdm.png)

This is how the page looks when deployed:

[the page on the server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4Ee2.png)

As you can see, input fields have border and are a little bit smaller.
But the biggest issue is that labels gone.

For example let me show everything that is related to **Email **field.

The cshtml view file source code is:

```
                <div class="form-group row" id="ClientData-content-area">
                    <div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <label asp-for="ClientData.Email" class="input-label"></label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                <input asp-for="ClientData.Email" class="form-control radius-border input-style margin-container" required />
                                <span asp-validation-for="ClientData.Email"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I inspected the page with devtools.
On localhost it is: `<label class="input-label" for="MerchantInvoiceId">Invoice #</label>`
On server it is: `<label asp-for="MerchantInvoiceId" class="input-label"></label>`

I test everything on same browser. Google chrome.
There are no any errors in console.

Any ideas what might be wrong? Thanks